# How to check data type of user input like: int, double and string in c

Tags: c

I am trying to check data type of an user input which can be a int,double, string/char etc. Here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char input[100] = "";
    double x;
    int num;
    char str[20] = "";
    int assignments[5] = { 0 };

    printf("Pls. provide unput");
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);

    if (sscanf(input, "%d", &num) == 1)
    {
        printf("the input is a int.\n");
    }
    else if (strtod(input, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("the input is a double\n");
    }
    else if (sscanf(input, "%s", &str) == 1)
    {
        printf("the input is a string\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("input not recognized");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but it is not working properly — specially the `double` part.  For any input of `double` it recognize it as an `int`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Integer can be read correctly as `double`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I See your point, the, a blunt way, but `%d.%d` can be used for double, if you stick to the `abc.xyz` format. :)

Comment: double as `3.1e2`, `inf` ...

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that is why I mentioned of the format :)

Comment: strtod("123", &endp), endp-->'\0' but int.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes, that's the thing from your earlier comment.....

Comment: Can use `sizeof()` operator.

Comment: you might want to look at this compiler extension for gcc. <https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you scan char array no need for address "str" instead of "&str", character arrays decay to a pointer.

Now coming to the main issue with why you are having trouble. Remember all integers are also doubles/floats. i.e integers are perfect subset of floats. So if you check for integer/read into int variable first, you will always match any float as float input by user will be truncated to int when reading and hence you will never hit branch checking for double.

The way to fix it is to first test for floating point number.So read input into double, then if it is true you test if it is an integer by casting it to integer and seeing relative difference to see if it is less than some tolerance.

So code that fixes this can be seen below

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "math.h"


int main()
{
   char input[100] = "";
   double x;
   int num;
   char str[20] = "";
   int assignment[5] = {0};
   double tolerance = 1e-12;

   printf("Pls. provide input: ");
   fgets(input, 100, stdin);

   if (sscanf(input, "%lf", &x) == 1) { 
      // Is it a number? All integers are also doubles.
      num = (int)x; // We cast to int. 
      if ( fabs(x - num)/x > tolerance ) {
         printf("The input is a floating point\n");
      } else { 
         printf("The input is a integer\n");
      }
   } else if (sscanf(input, "%s", str) == 1) { 
      // Check if it is string
      printf("The input is a string\n");
   } else { 
      // No match error.
      printf("input not recognized\n");
   }
}
```

**SAMPLE**

gcc test.c

Pls. provide input: 3
The input is a integer.

Pls. provide input: 3.3
The input is a floating point.

**NOTE** You should use something more meaningful like machine precision rather than the tolerance that i show.

Comment: You must have seen a very early version of the question which got fixed in the first 5 minutes to have seen the `scanf()` with the wrong format — there's no record of that in the question history (but there wouldn't be if it was fixed before comments were added).

Comment: Okay I have edited to reflect that. But the original code posted by the author of the question still has the bug where he uses &str instead of str.

Comment: Indubitably.  What you've provided is considerably better. I'm not sure quite what's best to do. Functions like `strtod()` and `strtol()` tell you where they stopped converting and whether they detected errors, and you could use the end position to scan to end of line to ensure that everything got converted, and then you'd be able to try integers first and doubles later. The error detection with `strtol()` and `strtod() is tricky stuff, though, which is one main reason I'm not sure it is appropriate for the OP yet. The alternatives are bad too. Maybe the `%n` conversion specification helps?

Answer (score 0):

No surprises that the code will detect input of a floating point value as an `int`.  For example, given input of `2.3`,  `sscanf()`'s `%d` format will recognise the `2` as an `int`, and stop when it encounters the decimal point.   The decimal point will be there to be read by a subsequent input operation.

Try processing the string in order to check what the string contains.    Criteria you could use include looking for non-numeric characters (anything other than digits, decimal points, or sign characters) - if those are found, deem the input to be a string.   If only digits and sign characters are found, but no decimal point interpret the string as an `int`.   If digits, sign, and decimal points are found, interpret as a `float`.

You can also do other techniques, for example, if you want to treat `2.3E32` as a floating point, rather than as a string.

You can tailor the above however you like, depending on your needs.

What ever you do, however, you need to do error checking on every operation (reading, interpreting the string, etc).    You are best off assuming the input string contains garbage unless it passes your tests - assuming by default it contains an integer may well get you in trouble with input like `2XYZ`.